# 550 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable or not local

Tags: migration

my domain is hosted on a plesk panel control, I had migrated my domain webmail from plesk to zoho.I am facing a bouncing problem when I send mail from another webmail of other domain

Answer (score 0):

As Per [How to fix “550 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable or not local” in Plesk servers](https://bobcares.com/blog/how-to-fix-550-requested-action-not-taken-mailbox-unavailable-or-not-local-in-odin-plesk-servers/)

> In Plesk Windows servers, the default mail server is MailEnable. Plesk
>   account owners in these servers sometimes report the MailEnable error
>   SMTP server response: 550 Requested action not taken: mailbox
>   unavailable or not local when trying to send out mails or when
>   managing their account functions through the Plesk panel.
>
> **What does this error mean ?**
>
> It means MailEnable found the recipient domain of a mail in the
>   server, but couldn’t locate the email username. For example, let’s say
>   MailEnable received a mail to be delivered to
>   “mail-recipient@domain.com”. It would look for active mail services
>   for “domain.com”, and then for the inbox of “mail-recipient”. If it is
>   able to locate “domain.com”, but not “mail-recipient@domain.com”, this
>   error would be returned. We’ve been able to prevent server incidents
>   by up to 15% by using our proactive server checks ([click here to see
>   how we improve web hosting support](https://bobcares.com/remote-technical-support/dedicated-support-services/features/)).
>
> **Why does this happen?**
>
> We have noted the following situations in which this error is reported
>   by Plesk panel accounts.
>
> 1. For some unknown reason, when the recipient mailbox was disabled by the account owner, or because of a bug in Plesk.
> 2. When the email account is hosted elsewhere (like Google Apps), but the domain has mail services enabled in the local server. Bonus tip :
>      If the customer receives this error (as shown below) while using the
>      Plesk panel, it means that the administrator email for the domain is
>      set to an email account which is either disabled in the local server,
>      or is hosted elsewhere.
>
>    Warning: Unable to send notification: mail() failed: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 550 Requested action not taken:
>      mailbox unavailable or not local
>
> **How to fix this error?**
>
> 1. If the email service for the domain is hosted elsewhere, just turn off mail services by going to:
>
>    `Domains > Mail > Disable Mail`
> 2. If the MX points to the local server, check if the email account is disabled, and if so, re-enable it.